# What Is The Standard .NET Control Border Color?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to match the standard .NET control border color in a custom control but am having trouble finding out what it is.

I'm guessing that it is a system color such as `ControlDark` or `ControlDarkDark` but checking with a color picker tells me otherwise.

Rather than set a fixed color, I'd prefer to adopt the way that other form controls are painted, assuming they use a system color.

Does anyone know the system color that's used? Or have any other clues on this?

Comment: UPDATE: Checking through the environment colors for the ones which match the actual border color (RGB 100,100,100), `WindowsFrame` might be correct. Any thoughts? I guess I could try changing this and see what the result is.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of .NET Framework desktop UI you are using?

If you are using Windows Forms, to determine whether a color is System's color, you should check the property of that color by checking the value of `Color.IsSystemColor` property.

Please consult [Color.IsSystemColor property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.issystemcolor?view=netframework-4.7?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4040024).

To get the known list of Windows Forms system color, you could examine the enum values of `KnownColor` enum. Each enum value within `KnownColor` is the color value that is convertible to Color value.

For more information on `KnownColor`, please consult [KnownColor enum documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.knowncolor?view=netframework-4.7?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4040024).

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained well enough; I'm trying to find out what design color the control borders are, if any, for example, of a `TextBox` control. I'm not trying to find out the actual color or the environment system color. I want to then set my custom control border to be the same, eg, `ControlDarkDark`.